# How to set webview width the same for small screen and large screens

Tags: android

In my app i make use of webview. The webviews are taking the sizes of the images that i load into them. Now is the problem that if i want to view them on a 7" or 10" tablet screen i'm getting a white border on the right side of the webview.

So i want that the images fit into the webviews on small and large screens.

This is the code for a webview that i have:

```
package be.weaterApp.weatherwatch;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class Dauwpunten extends Activity{
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.temperaturen);

    String loadUrl = "http://www.meteociel.fr/cartes_obs/pointrosee.png";

    // initialize the browser object
    WebView browser = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webviewt);

    browser.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    browser.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    browser.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    final ProgressDialog pd = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "De kaart wordt geladen...", true);
    //setContentView(R.layout.weerforu);

    browser.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
      @Override
      public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        pd.dismiss();
      }
    });
    try {
        // load the url
        browser.loadUrl(loadUrl);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

And this is for the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >






<com.android.sdk.mobgold.MobRequest
    android:id="@+id/ad"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dip"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:clickable="true" />


<android.webkit.WebView
    android:id="@+id/webviewt"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

</android.webkit.WebView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would wrap that PNG in a small HTML file and set its image tag to 100% width.

Comment: The problem is that i have to do that then for all my images. If i could change something in my temperaturen.xml then that would be easier because all my java files are linking to this xml file.

Comment: First of all, you could host on your website a dynamic wrapper HTML page that shows the requested PNG file according to a URL query parameter. Another option is constructing that HTML page as a String in your app code and load that String in your WebView.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a webview whose size is set to the size of an image, the webview is going to be different sizes on different resolution devices. A better way to do it (if you want your app to appear the same on all screen sizes) would be to use weights (`android:layout_weight="X"`) to create a proportional layout which doesn't depend on the size of the content, but makes the webview take up a certain percentage of the screen instead. This way, you can make your webview (for example) take up exactly 50% of the screen regardless of the size of the device.

Comment: Can you post an example of this?

Comment: Sorry, quick question: it looks like the webview is set to fill the entire screen. Is the white space INSIDE your webview? I.e. the webview is the entire screen and there is just white around the image because the image doesn't fill the webview?

Comment: Yes, the white space is inside the webview. So maybe i have to load the webview zoomed in?

Comment: Yes, you will have to do something more complicated - either zoom the webview or do some sort of image scaling (but that  would require something on the web server, similar to the other answer's suggestion, rather than an XML change)... You'll want to do something like call http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#setInitialScale%28int%29 setInitialScale() to make it bigger. You could also define the ScaleX and ScaleY fields in XML. But you probably only want to do the additional zoom for large screens... use the `layout-hdpi` folder, perhaps.

Comment: The ScaleX and ScaleY is not recognized in my xml.

Comment: see the documentation here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:scaleX